# How can i create subdomain on route 53 using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain

Hope you guys are doing well,
I need a help in route 53. i need a script using which i can create sub-domain using php. I have system in which if user is getting registered with us then we are assign a sub-domain to them for profile page. Right now we are doing it manually we want to make it dynamic. is it possible to make sub-domain using PHP?

Answer (score 3):

You can use AWS SDK to create sub-domains through PHP.

Use `changeResourceRecordSets` method and add CNAME entry to `ResourceRecordSet` Array.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Route53.Route53Client.html#_changeResourceRecordSets

Comment: You have any example for it ?

Comment: Sorry got the example in above link